# how to change the icon of application in windows 8 rt?

Tags: windows-runtime, icons, winrt-xaml

I want to change the default icon of application in windows 8 rt application, in property page of the application the icon source is disabled, how can i change it to new picture??
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to solution explorer.
In solution explorer find your project folder.
Then find "Package.appxmanifest" Under that. 
you can edit everything you want in Package.appxmanifest.